# on selected method array-adapter

Tags: android, adapter

I made `onItemSelected` method for a `Spinner` try to change a `TextView` which depends on the input of the `Spinner`. The problem is I get stuck with the first input and it's not changing once I chose different input.

Here is the method and the onselectmethod  in the MainActivity

```
public void listView(int index){

    int indexs=0;
    Cursor res= db.getMainData();
    if(res.moveToFirst()){
        PPLNAMERES.setText(res.getString(indexs));
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    PPLNAMERES = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.PPLNAMEGETNAME);
    listView(position);
}
```

getMainData method in the sqliteopenhelper class

```
   public Cursor getMainData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select NAMEPPL from " + Table_name2, null);
    return result;

     }
```

Comment: post you getMainData() and where do you initialize db?

Comment: please post the getMainData() method then, and show where you initialize the db object.... such as db = etc.

Comment: sorry for been late i just add the getmaindata method

Comment: are you sure your Cursor is not null running the query you have?

Comment: i fix it thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The error message says

`Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow`
So your query is returning 0 rows. Your if statement should read:

```
if(cur!=null){
    // Best to manage any non-null cursor as then it will be closed when the
    // activity is stopped
    startManagingCursor(cur);
    // Only if a row was found
    if(cur.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.d("debug Cursor" , "can be created");
        Log.d("KEY_PHOTO_HKID_HEX" , cur.getString(1));
        Log.d("KEY_PHOTO_ADDRESS_HEX" , cur.getString(2));
        Log.d("KEY_PHOTO_BANK_HEX" , cur.getString(3));
    }else{
        // Handle no rows returned
    }
}else{
    Log.d("debug Cursor" , "cannot be created");
}
```